# CPU reaching 100% with jboss eap 6.0

Tags: sql-server-2012, java-7, jboss-eap-6, struts-1

We are using jboss eap 6.0 with java 7 and struts 1.3 framework along with sql server 2012 ,hosted only one web application ,after 2 days CPU reaching 100%,Please suggest me.Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest examining query execution plans and perform needed query and index tuning as the first step. Make sure data types match for query parameters and literals to ensure indexes can be used efficiently.

Comment: Thank You .. Dan

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your application try to load  to any big size image anywhere. Also compare with the old version of app which was running ok.

Comment: Thank You Varun ,I will check

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the tips in the JBoss EAP 7 Performance Tuning Guide to help identify the Java threads that are causing the high CPU usage: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.1/html-single/performance_tuning_guide/#identifying_high_cpu

Most of the instructions in that guide can also be applied to JBoss EAP 6.

If you are a Red Hat Customer, there is also a Customer Portal Labs tool to help with identifying high CPU threads: https://access.redhat.com/labs/jvmpeg/